# Prove intrinsic metric does not equal metric induced

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $U= (0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ and consider the function $f:U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by:  $f(u,v)=(\sinh u\cos v, \sinh u\sin v, \cosh u).$

(i) Let $\mathbb{H}^{2} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid \, x^{2}+y^{2}-z^{2} = -1, \, \, z>0\}$ be the upper sheet of a hyperboloid in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and note the $S=\mathbb{H}^{2} \backslash \{(0,0,1)\}$. Prove the intrinsic metric $d_{int}$ on $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3}$ does not equal the metric induced by $d$.

So for this all I really know is that $\mathbb{H}^{2}$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\operatorname{arcosh}(-<x\mid y>)$ is a model for the hyperbolic plane, where $<\cdot \mid \cdot >$ is the Lorentz scalar product. I've been told to consider the points $A=(\sinh u,0,\cosh u)$ and $B=(-\sinh u,0,\cosh u)$ as a hint but I'm unsure how to.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I'm not sure if what was in the previous parts will be relevant, but if so I do already know that $f(u,v)$ is a surface patch and I have the first and second fundamentals forms of $S=f(U)$ along with the Gauss Curvature of $S$

Comment: For the sake of clarity can you define the intrinsic metric $d_{int}$?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this but I think the intrinsic metric should be defined as $d(x,y)= inf\{L(\gamma) \mid \, \gamma \, \text{a path from u to v}\}$ atleast thats what my notes hint at...

Comment: Good-natured expository tip: Define symbols before using them, e.g., say at the start that $S = f(U)$, that $d_{\text{int}}$ is the shortest-path distance, define the Lorentz inner product before defining $d$, etc. And a LaTeX tip: Use `\newcommand{\brak}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}` or some such for angle brackets. <> The mathematical question is, "Show the upper sheet of the hyperboloid is not isometric to the hyperbolic plane." You've indicated the Gaussian curvature of $S$ is known; can you take it from there?